# Some of my Code gets skipped over Why?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to write this program and i think i almost have it, but im coming up with in error that part of my code gets skiped over why? When i go to run my program and hit the line button the text display says Input Y instead of X so i know that the code in between the commented out lines is not running ,or is and isnt working properly. So my question is why is that part of the code being skiped over and not ran?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cad);
    ourSurface = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    FrameLayout v = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.display);
    v.addView(ourSurface);
    ourSurface.setRenderer(new GLRenderer());

    final TextView info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    Button line = (Button) findViewById(R.id.line);
    final Button enter = (Button)findViewById(R.id.enter);
    EditText cl = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cl);
    final String value = cl.getText().toString();

    line.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                coords = Float.parseFloat(value);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e){};

//------------------------------------------------

            info.setText("Input x");
            enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    linep.add((float)coords);                   
                }
            });             
//-----------------------------------------         
            info.setText("Input y");
            enter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {               
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    linep.add((float)coords);
                    indexP.add((short)p);
                }
            });
        }
    }): 
}
```

Comment: (1) what lines are skipped (2) plz format your code.

Comment: add some error handling to your catch-block above info.setText. Are you sure there is no NumberFormatException?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't skipping anything - it's doing what it's supposed to do ... it seems that you don't understand how listeners are working:

```
you set text of info to "input x" 
then you set the on click listener of enter
then you set text of info to "input y"
then you set the on click listener of enter again
```

so at the end 
two first lines are reset by the second lines ... 
it's like this

```
infotext = "input x"
enterclick = some code
infotext = "input y"
enderclick = some other code
```

Line buton does not even have on click listener set so it does nothing.

Comment: I see what you mean. Thank you.. So in other words I need to change it so when the line button is pressed that infotext displays input x then do then enter buttons?

Comment: yes ... code that neads to be run when something is clicked must be inside of onClick method ...